# Why does ServiceStack return 404 with this configuration?

Tags: servicestack

I have the following configuration.

```xml
<location path="services">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If I add another `<system.webServer />` section, not within a `location` element, ServiceStack returns 404 for all requests. Remove it, and everything works again.

Here's an example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.926 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2012 23:15:46 GMT
Content-Length: 1528

Handler for Request not found: 


Request.ApplicationPath: /MyWebApp.Web.UI
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /MyWebApp.Web.UI/services/echo/
Request.FilePath: /MyWebApp.Web.UI/services/echo/
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.MapPath('~'): D:\Lib\MyWebApp\2013\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Web.UI
Request.Path: /MyWebApp.Web.UI/services/echo/
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.ResolvedPathInfo: /services/echo
Request.PhysicalPath: D:\Lib\MyWebApp\2013\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Web.UI\services\echo\
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath: D:\Lib\MyWebApp\2013\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Web.UI\
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /MyWebApp.Web.UI/services/echo/
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: http://localhost/MyWebApp.Web.UI/services/echo/
Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /MyWebApp.Web.UI/services/echo/
Request.Url.Fragment: 
Request.Url.Host: localhost
Request.Url.LocalPath: /MyWebApp.Web.UI/services/echo/
Request.Url.Port: 80
Request.Url.Query: 
Request.Url.Scheme: http
Request.Url.Segments: System.String[]
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: D:\Lib\MyWebApp\2013\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Web.UI
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [global.asax,global.asax.cs,header.html,list.html,login.html,MyWebApp.web.ui.csproj,MyWebApp.web.ui.csproj.user,packages.config,web.config,bin,humanresources,js,obj,properties,styles,_sgbak]
App.DefaultHandler: DefaultHttpHandler
App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: GET|/MyWebApp.Web.UI/services/echo/|D:\Lib\MyWebApp\2013\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Web.UI\services\echo\
```

Is it not possible to have another `system.webServer` section? I'd like to add IIS url rewriting rules there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra `system.webServer` declaration might be interfering with ServiceStack's auto-inferencing of the hosted path from your Web.Config.

You can try to set the path manually to see if that helps, e.g in your AppHost.Configure():

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    HandlerFactoryPath = "services",
});
```

Comment: That appears to be it. Thanks for the fix (and a great library).

Comment: Thanks, I had same problem in Silverlight using Ria services.